# не загружаются в БД символы от 00 до 09 в String

Tags: java, android, строки, sqlite

Проблема в том, что не могу загрузить в БД `String` выражения от "00" до "09".
Выводит либо 0, либо 9.
Вот собственно код создания БД и метод добавления в него:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ALARMCLOCK ("
    + "_id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + "HOURS TEXT, "
    + "MINUTES TEXT, "
    + "DAYS TEXT);");
}
public static void insertAlarmCLock(SQLiteDatabase db, String hours, String minutes, String days){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("HOURS", hours);
    contentValues.put("MINUTES", minutes);
    contentValues.put("DAYS", days);
    db.insert("ALARMCLOCK", null, contentValues);
}
```

само добавление:

```
if(hours.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    h = "00";
                }
                else {
                    h = hours.getText().toString();
                }
                if(minutes.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    min = "00";
                }
                else {
                    min = minutes.getText().toString();
                }
                days = buffer.toString();
                AlarmClockDB.insertAlarmClock(db, h, min, days);
```

загрузка из БД:

```
cursor = db.query("ALARMCLOCK", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        String[] from = new String[]{"HOURS", "MINUTES", "DAYS"};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.hours, R.id.minutes, R.id.days};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, cursor, from, to, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Тут у вас `int[] to = new int[]{R.id.hours, R.id.minutes, R.id.days};`  **integer**, однозначно теперь ваше **to** без вторых нулей останется.

Comment: Останется **to** без нулей, появится на екране - и будете думать что в базе не сохраняется ноль.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а как к этому относится? Здесь же определяются айдишники TextView в макете, а не сами данные. Или я что то упускаю?

Comment: парадокс, если перед нулями приписать любой символ, то выводит всё выражение корректно, а просто два нуля не хочет

Comment: у вас проблема с выводом! Поменяйте int[] to на string[] to хотя бы

Comment: @nick_n_a я еще раз говорю, там задаются айдишники макетов, они всегда типа `int`, они к самим данным никакого отношения не имеют. Со `String` будет ошибка несоответствия типов данных.

Comment: @nick_n_a посмотрел с помощью `moveToNext()`, что записывается в БД. В общем, дело даже не в выводе, нулей там и в помине нет.

Comment: Мне кажется что в даном случае, что бы долго не мучатся, проще поставить выравнивание вывода типа 0:00(c#) или %02i (c++) (в java что-то такое должно быть)

Comment: @nick_n_a, тоже уже думал, но у меня из БД напрямую данные записываются в адаптер. Я думал, что есть обходные пути, жаль мало людей посмотрело вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал TimePicker, написал свой адаптер, всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

При переводе из типа String к одному из целочисленных типов (например, int) к int присваивается только число. Так из `00` вы получаете `0`, а из `09` - `9`.
Просмотрите тот файл, где находится ваше добавление с условиями `if`. Уточните точный тип переменных при определении `h, min, days`.

Comment: но у меня по сути нет перевода из одного типа в другой. Все переменные типа `String`, столбцы в БД типа `TEXT`

Comment: ответ неоднозначный, из области ищите где теряется число. Где-то там.

Comment: @Ivan, вы можете посмотреть данные, добавленные в таблицу с помощью sqlite3. Подробнее см. [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html)